# Extracting ee.Geometry.Point from randomPoints

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to extract the points from the following function in Google Earth Engine
`random_points = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(region, 1,0,1)`

When i use `.getInfo()`, it tells me that this is an ee.ComputedObject. The actual random points don’t seem to bin this datastructure.

I can display the random points in `Map.addLayer(random_points,{'color': '0000FF'},'randoms')`

I am using Python for this, but I also use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you are exactly after but I think you are trying to change the object type to geometry? In javascript that looks like this:

```
var getinf = random_points.getInfo()
print(getinf)

Map.addLayer(random_points,{'color': '0000FF'},'randoms')

var extractGeom = random_points.geometry()
print(extractGeom, 'extractGeom')

var extractcoords = random_points.geometry().coordinates()
print(extractcoords, 'extractcoords')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0ded8fefccc17a2ef529d4afa6038152

Comment: thank you, thats what i was looking for in terms of javascript. I also figured out the python code. getInfo() is actually what you need to use:

```
 random_points = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(region= my_region,
                                                      points= 1,
                                                      seed= 0, 
                                                      maxError= 1) 
return_coordinate = random_points.getInfo()["features"][0]['geometry']['coordinates']
```